# Determine if system has a potential given velocity expression

Tags: potential

I have a polynomial expression for velocity which is a function of the position. I am to determine if a potential exists for this system. I am thinking no, that the phase space will not be bounded. Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Can we see the expression for velocity? You can calculate the force however and use Stokes theorem to see if the force is conservative.

Comment: Okay I did try calculating the force using the Lagrangian and an arbitrary potential.  I did not think about Stokes theorem.  I hesitate to put the exact expression since it is for homework.

Comment: See the second comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946559/stokes-theorem-on-conservative-vector-fields-and-whether-parametrization-is-a